# compare one row with multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Ex: I have other main table which is having below data

```
Create table dbo.Main_Table
(
ID INT,
SDate Date
)
Insert Into dbo.Main_Table   Values (1,'01/02/2018')
Insert Into dbo.Main_Table   Values (2,'01/30/2018')

Create table dbo.test
(
ID INT,
SDate Date
)
Insert Into dbo.test Values (1,'01/01/2018')
Insert Into dbo.test Values (1,'01/02/2018')
Insert Into dbo.test Values (1,'01/30/2018')

Insert Into dbo.test Values (2,'10/01/2018')
Insert Into dbo.test Values (2,'01/02/2018')
Insert Into dbo.test Values (2,'01/30/2018')
```

I would like to compare  data in main table data with test table. We have to join based on ID and if date match found then "yes" else "No". We have to compare one row with multiple rows.

Please let me know if any questions , thanks for you;re help

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with main_table (id, sdate) as
  2    (select 1, date '2018-01-02' from dual union all
  3     select 2, date '2018-01-30' from dual union all
  4     select 3, date '2018-07-25' from dual
  5    ),
  6  test_table (id, sdate) as
  7    (select 1, date '2018-01-02' from dual union all
  8     select 2, date '2018-08-30' from dual
  9    )
 10  select m.id,
 11    m.sdate,
 12    case when m.sdate = t.sdate then 'yes' else 'no' end status
 13  from main_table m left join test_table t on t.id = m.id
 14  order by m.id;

        ID SDATE    STATUS
---------- -------- ------
         1 02.01.18 yes
         2 30.01.18 no
         3 25.07.18 no

SQL>
```

**[EDIT, after reading the comment - if you find a match, you don't need that ID at all]**

Here you are:

```
SQL> with test (id, sdate) as
  2    (select 1, date '2018-01-01' from dual union all
  3     select 1, date '2018-01-02' from dual union all
  4     select 1, date '2018-01-30' from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 2, date '2018-10-01' from dual union all
  7     select 2, date '2018-01-02' from dual union all
  8     select 2, date '2018-01-30' from dual
  9    )
 10  select id, sdate
 11  from test t
 12  where not exists (select null
 13                    from test t1
 14                    where t1.id = t.id
 15                      and t1.sdate = to_date('&par_sdate', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
Enter value for par_sdate: 2018-01-01

        ID SDATE
---------- ----------
         2 2018-01-30
         2 2018-01-02
         2 2018-10-01

SQL> /
Enter value for par_sdate: 2018-01-02

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: It looks great, thanks! one quick question :) . the intend is different- its my fault -

Comment: test table is oracle one and date will pass from SQL server DB and it is fixed  date. For example i have passed 01/01/2018 to oracle and it is matching one of rows in ID 1 - then we are good and not matching any of the rows in ID2- so i need only top row from ID2 (that will be latest date).  only non matched top 1 ..I hope it is clear. thanks

Comment: Clear? Not really. What is *main_table* used for? Now MS SQL Server comes into the game - how, exactly? (I know nothing about it.) What would be the result you expect in all possible cases? What if nothing matches? What if all IDs match? Perhaps you should modify the question and explain it better. If it is complex, don't do it as a comment as it is difficult to read and understand.

Comment: yeah sorry/! let me make it easy. I could of enter only date in main table.  I think better way is create one variable in Oracle. check for match - if all IDs match then i don't need data as well. I'm concern about non matched ones.

Comment: OK, so you don't need the *main_table* at all - you'll pass a parameter (a DATE value). It will be compared to dates in the *temp_table*. What do you want to return if you find a match, and what do you want to return if you don't find a match per each ID?

Comment: if we find a match i don't need that ID at all. If we don't find a match then ID and latest date (order by desc)- only one row per id where there is no match

Comment: Looks great! thanks for you;re time, much appreciated. But my only concern is performance -  i need compare 1 date with 90000 rows- is there any better way to compare. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. 90K rows isn't that much. Anyway: create index on ID and SDATE columns. Check explain plan.

Comment: Yeah! I just have read only permissions ..need to find out best way to get data.

Comment: It seems that you have to run, but your left leg is broken. You'll have to talk to DBA, I presume.